# Overlapping range for two number pairs

Tags: java, list

Is there any easy way to define overlapping range for two number pairs?
For instance,
Pair1 = [360, 780]
Pair2 = [420, 800]

The answer would be [420, 780]

Comment: `result = {max(pair1[0], pair2[0]), min(pair1[1], pair2[1])}`

Comment: check the first example http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=greedyAlg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your intervals overlap.

Then take the max of the lower bound and the min of the upper bound for both pairs.

```
int lower = Math.max(myPair1.x1, myPair2.x1);
int upper = Math.min(myPair1.x2, myPair2.x2);

if(lower < upper)
  return new Pair(lower, upper)
else 
  throw new CustomException("Intervals not overlap")
```

Comment: Is there any quick way to check whether the intervals overlap?

Comment: You'll have to check that the lower bound of the new interval is inferior than the upper bound of the new interval

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class like

```
class Range {
    final int start;
    final int end;
    private Range(int start; int end) { this.start = start; this.end = end; }
    public static Range of(int start, int end) { return new Range(start, end); }
    public Range and(Range r) {
        return new Range(Math.max(start, r.start), Math.min(end, r.end);
    }
}
```

You could write

```
Range one = Range.of(360, 780);
Range two = Range.of(420, 800);
Range both = one.and(two);
```

Comment: What if there is no overlapping?

Comment: @whoAmI in that case `end` < `start` and you get an invalid range.  How you handle that depends on what you want it to do. It could throw an exception for example in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
int from = Math.max(pair1.getX(), pair2.getX());
int to = Math.min(pair1.getY(), pair2.getY());

if (from <= to) {
   return new Pair(from, to);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `from <= to`?  A one element range is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat misuse of `java.awt.geom`, try it:

```
public static double[] createIntersection(double[] a1, double[] a2) {
    Rectangle2D r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(), r2 = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    r1.setFrameFromDiagonal(a1[0], 0, a1[1], 1);
    r2.setFrameFromDiagonal(a2[0], 0, a2[1], 1);
    Rectangle2D r3 = r1.createIntersection(r2);
    return new double[] { r3.getMinX(), r3.getMaxX() };
}
```

Comment: Seems to be overkilling for such a simple task.